# Open Generated html file in Safari

Tags: ios, xcode, safari

Is there any way i can open a saved .html file in Documents directory of the application, in Safari. 
   I have a Template.html file that i change depending on user choices and saving it to a temp.html file, how to open it in safari?

Comment: Since apps are sandboxed Safari has no access to your apps document directory. What you could do is open you HTML file in a `UIWebView` and display in your app.

Comment: what i need is to have access to add to home button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't open File-URLs in iOS' Safari-App via [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:] due to sandbox restrictments.

You have 2 options:

a) Upload that file to a server and then open it in the Safari-App with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"http://..."];

b) Embed a Safari-WebView in your app which displays the html-file, like so:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
[self.view addSubView:webView];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:...];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

**self** is a UIViewController here.

**EDIT**

To add a Share-Button with proper logic, you can put the ViewController, that contains the UIWebView, inside a UINavigationController and add a UIBarButtonItem of type *UIBarButtonSystemItemAction* to it's NavigationBar. If the BarButtonItem gets tapped, you show a [a UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(shareButtonTapped:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
}

- (void)shareButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:... applicationActivities:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

For more Infos on using UIActivityViewController, see [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/)

Comment: a) i would like the app to work in offline mode b) tried that...and it somehow it works...but i need the share button or more precise add to screen

Comment: Well, that's another question ;)

Comment: I have edited my answer to describe the basic steps for supporting a Share-Feature.