# How to load HTML string in browser in swift 2?

Tags: html, swift, browser, swift2

To load HTML string in webview I use that code

```
webView.loadHTMLString(embeddedString, baseURL: nil)
```

How can I load HTML string in browser like safari or chrome when a tableViewCell is tapped?

Comment: Do you want to navigate to Safari when tapping the cell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Generated html file in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310270/open-generated-html-file-in-safari)

Comment: [Yes, @Ahmed F]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this may be work

```
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "UrlOfYourFileWhereToLoad")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: fileURL)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```